# How to alter a shortcut to a program so as it can run as administrator?

Tags: windows-7

I sometimes forget to right click and select "Run as administrator" so I want to edit the shortcut so as I will only have to double click the program right away. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the shortcut, select Properties, select Compatibility tab, check the "Run as Administrator" box.